# Changing the order of integration: How to set the bounds

Tags: integration, bounds-of-integration

A derivation is given in a textbook. Here, $F$ is a probabilistic distribution function, which means that: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(t) dt = 1$$

At one step, they change the order of integration:

\begin{align}
H(x) &= \int_{-\infty}^x \int_s^x dt \: dF(s) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^x \int_{-\infty}^t dF(s) \: dt
\end{align}

My question is, how did they come up with the bounds in the second line?

Comment: That may depend on the actual function $F$ : do you have more information about this function ?

Comment: Yes. $F$ is a probabilistic distribution function, thus $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(t) dt = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a function $ f : \mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $, such that $ \left(\forall s\in\mathbb{R}\right),\ f_{s}:t\mapsto f\left(t,s\right) $ is continious and integrable in $ \mathbb{R} $, and that $ g_{s}:x\mapsto\int\limits_{x}^{+\infty}{f\left(t,s\right)\mathrm{d}t} $ is also continious and integrable in $ \mathbb{R},\ \left(\forall s\in\mathbb{R}\right)\cdot $

Let $ x $ be a real.

For $ s \leq x $, denoting $ \left(\forall t\in\left]-\infty,x\right]\right),\ g_{s}\left(t\right)=\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}f\left(t,s\right),\ \ \ \textrm{If }t\geq s\\ 0,\ \ \ \textrm{If }t\leq s\end{aligned}\right. $, we have :

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{x}{\int_{s}^{x}{f\left(t,s\right)\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}s}=\int_{-\infty}^{x}{\int_{-\infty}^{x}{g_{s}\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}s} $$

Using Fubini's theorem we get : \begin{aligned} \int_{-\infty}^{x}{\int_{s}^{x}{f\left(t,s\right)\mathrm{d}t}\,\mathrm{d}s}&=\int_{-\infty}^{x}{\int_{-\infty}^{x}{g_{s}\left(t\right)\mathrm{d}s}\,\mathrm{d}t}\\ &=\int_{-\infty}^{x}{\int_{-\infty}^{t}{f\left(t,s\right)\mathrm{d}s}\,\mathrm{d}t} \end{aligned}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't completely understand though why $g_s(t)$ is defined like that for $t \geq s$ and $t \leq s$.